# Terminology: Upper limit and lower limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, terminology

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. It defines:

$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m≥n} x_m)=\inf_{n≥1}(\sup_{m≥n}x_m)$

How should I understand the notation of the definition? Specifically the $m≥n$ and $n≥1$ terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\sup_{m\geq n} x_m$ is just a short way to write $\sup\{x_m: m\geq n\}=\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...\}$, the supremum of the sequence $(x_m)$ starting from the $n$th element.

Similarly, if we let $y_n=\sup_{m\geq n} x_m$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\inf_{n\geq 1} y_n$ is just $\inf\{y_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Well, for every constant $n$ we just define $y_n=\sup\{x_m: m\geq n\}=\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$. This way we get a new sequence $(y_n)$, the the upper limit of $x_n$ is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$. So in this definition we don't take $m\to\infty$, $m$ is just an index which we need to define the numbers $y_n$.

Answer (score 3):

At the limit the sequence has an upper bound.

The sequence can do things in the "short-term" or when $n$ is "small" that we will ignore.  But eventually $n$ will be big enough, that increasing $n$ will not have any bearing on the the supremum of the tail of the sequence for values bigger than $n.$

$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m≥n} x_m)$

When $n$ is large and we look at the subsequence when $m>n$ that subsequence has an upper bound and that is the limsup of the sequence.

$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \inf_{n≥1}(\sup_{m≥n}x_m)$

This says to look at the upper bound of the entire sequence.  The supremum of the sequence to the right of $n$ is less than or equal to the supremum of the sequence including $n.$  When $n$ gets to be large enough, we have found the smallest value of the sequence to the right of $n.$ And this is also the limsup of the sequence.

The sequence will be arbitrarily close to the limsup infinitely many times.

Answer (score 2):

$\inf_{\text{condition}}(\text{quantity})$ (and similar for $\sup$) needs to be understood as $\inf\{\text{quanity}\mid\text{condition}\}$, i.e as the infimum of the *set* of the quantities satisfying the condition (and similar for the supremum).

Thus, $\sup_{m\ge n}x_m$ is actually $\sup\{x_m\mid m\ge n\}=\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots\}$. Similarly:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\inf_{n\ge 1}\sup_{m\ge n}x_m&=&\inf\{\sup\{x_m\mid m\ge n\}\mid n\ge 1\}\\&=&\inf\{\sup\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\ldots\},\sup\{x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots\},\sup\{x_3,x_4,\ldots\},\ldots\}\end{array}$$

Note as a set gets smaller, it's supremum gets *smaller* and its infimum gets *bigger*.